# Rest-assured. How to check if not empty array is returned?

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

I have the following code which should test my RESTful API:

```
given().baseUri("http://...").get("/categories/all")
    .then()
    .body(
        "results",  not(empty())
    );
```

The API returns the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "type": "NotFoundException"
    }
}
```

And I want the test to fail for such response. But the test passes.

How can I modify the test to make it fail? It should only pass if the API returns an object which contains a not-empty array in the "results" key. It should fail when the "results" key does not exists, contains empty array or when it contains something that is not an array.

Comment: Why not return a List instead, and use the .isEmpty() check ?

Comment: Just a note: if you want to be RESTful, do not return error code in the body response, but use standard [HTTP return codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) (`Not Found` is `404`)

Comment: @Stultuske I do not fully understand your comment. Should I return a list from the REST API? But the API does not work correctly, it does not return a list and I want to check it.

Comment: Much depends on how you implement it. If you don't want to change the code, you can still go Arrays.asList(myArrayName); and call isEmpty() on that

Comment: @ThanksForAllTheFish I know :) . I do return the 404 response code. The response contents only contain additional information. But in my test I want to check the "results" key anyway.

Comment: @Stultuske I think I found an easier, more concise way to do this. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

```
given().baseUri("http://...").get("/categories/all")
    .then()
    .body(
        "results", hasSize(greaterThan(0))
    );
```

It fails if "results" is an empty array or not an array.
It passes if "results" is a not-empty array.
It reports an error in a readable way, e.g.:

```
Expected: a collection with size a value greater than <0>
Actual: null
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem but in my case the endpoint direcly returns an array. My solution for this:

```
@Test
public void testNotEmpty() {
    uAssured.given()
            .when()
                .get("resources/totest")
            .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body("$.size()", greaterThan(0));
}
```

For the example above the following should work as well:

```
@Test
public void testNotEmpty() {
    uAssured.given()
            .when()
                .get("resources/totest")
            .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body("results.size()", greaterThan(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the array is not empty you can use the **not(emptyArray)** method.

```
   given()
  .baseUri("http://...")
  .get("/categories/all")
  .then()
  .body("results", not(emptyArray()));
```

use emptyArray method from org.hamcrest.Matcher

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and what I found was that the following instruction worked:

```
given().baseUri("http://...").get("/categories/all")
.then()
.assertThat().body(notNullValue());
```

I tried everything above and had no luck.